# How to turn off I18N in django-cms 2.4.0?

Tags: django, django-cms, django-i18n

Since upgrading to django-cms 2.4.0, it seems I cannot turn off I18N to remove the /en/ from the url.

I have set `USE_I18N = False` and commented `#'django.core.context_processors.i18n',` and `#'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',` as the documentation recommends and used to work. However all my pages in /admin/cms/page/ now have a title of "None" and no longer load. If I turn in I18N it works, but that is not a good solution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UkFU.jpg

Anybody know what is going on here.

Comment: Ok, so you previously had i18n enabled, and now you want to disabled it, correct?

Comment: I previously had it disabled with Django==1.4.5 and django-cms==2.3.5. I have now installed Django==1.5.1 and django-cms==2.4.0. This problem arose, so to troubleshoot, I enabled and it went away. Turn it back to False and back to the picture above. This includes with a fresh database.

Comment: do you have `MultilingualURLMiddleware` in your middlewares.py? if so, remove it

Comment: I do not have a middlewares.py. If I do, I don't know where that would be.

Comment: According to Divio, this may be a real issue, https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1715.